# Get subscribed podcasts using ITunes SDK

Tags: c#, com, itunes-sdk

How can I get a list of all subscribed podcasts using the Itunes SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return you the playlist with all subscribed podcasts:

```
var podCastPlaylist = new iTunesAppClass()
    .LibrarySource
    .Playlists
    .Cast<IITPlaylist>()
    .First(pl => pl.Name == "Podcasts")
```

Comment: And it does, but what I am really looking for is the podcasts, not the episodes/tracks. I was hoping that could lead me to the URL's for the underlying feeds. Maybe it is simply not possible with the SDK?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the feed urls, podcast titles etc, from what I have been able to dig up.

You can get the podcast episodes tracks however, using the code supplied by Flagbug.